# Mapbox Marker Style/CSS not working in angular 8 application

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I have looked at a few other posts on here and none of them have been able to help me fix my issue.

I am adding a marker to my map using the following code:

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.className = 'marker';

new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
   .setLngLat(Bounds)
   .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25}) // add popups
   .setHTML('<h3>' + 'test' + '</h3><p>' + 'add stuff here' + '</p>'))
   .addTo(map);
```

I know that my lat/longs are correct because as seen in the attached picture the div is correctly showing up for the 'marker' in the console and on the map. Something is being whacky with my css. I currently have a class in my angular component css file titled .marker and another one titled .mapboxgl-marker but neither seem to be working correctly.

[image: Example of div location in map area]

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are there two )) at the end of `setHTML`? Is anything undefined?

Comment: Both of those are successfully paired to the right parentheses. Thanks for the thoughts, ended up figuring it out. answering question now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. I had to add the code below when adding the Marker as a new mapboxgl.Marker(). This was the ONLY way I was able to access the CSS for the marker.

```
el.setAttribute('style', 'width: 30px; height: 30px; background-color: blue');
```

If anyone else was able to access a mapbox Marker's css another way please feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it.

The class style I put in styles.scss on angular principal folder.

I hope will be help.